# Node.js return, callback and source code execution flow - Runtime

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, runtime, sails.js

I'm pretty confused by the way to work on node.js, I'm talking about callbacks, returns and how source code is executed.

I'm using sails.js but I don't think it's linked, it's more the way to JS works, I think.

Source code:

```
module.exports = function (req, res, callback) {
    if (req.session.authenticated) {
        // Accept user authentication.
        return callback();
    } else {
        // Not authenticated. Try auto authentication.
        if(validator.check([validator.rulesHardwareId(req.param('hardwareId'))])){
            Device.findOne({hardwareId: req.param('hardwareId')}, function(err, device){
                if(err){
                    return res.json({message: "You are not permitted to perform this action. You have to connect to the platform before. [Wrong hardwareId or DB error]", data: {err: err}, status: false}, 403);
                }

                if(device){
                    // Connect the device.
                    req.session.authenticated = true;
                    req.session.from = 'device';

                    // Search for the device's owner.
                    User.findOne({id: device.userId}, function(err, user){
                        if(err){
                            return res.json({message: "DB error.", data: {err: err}, status: false}, 403);
                        }

                        if(user){
                            // Add data about the user.
                            req.session.user = user;
                            return callback();
                        }else{
                            return res.json({message: "Device found but device's owner doesn't found.", data: {err: err}, status: false}, 403);
                        }
                    });
                }else{
                    return res.json({message: "You are not permitted to perform this action. You have to connect to the platform before. [Wrong hardwareId]", data: {err: err}, status: false}, 403);
                }
            });
        }
        return res.json({message: "You are not permitted to perform this action. You have to connect to the platform before. [Give hardwareId ?]", data: {}, status: false}, 403);

    }
};
```

The code is not so important, the thing is that I received this message: 
"You are not permitted to perform this action. You have to connect to the platform before. [Give hardwareId ?]"

But the action is CREATED. Okay, so I call the callback() and I return it, but the source code continue? And execute the last line? Why? I don't understand that.
If I put the last line in a ELSE, I receive the message "The action is created".

If someone could explain me.. I thought that add the return keyword was useful for prevent this, but it looks like I'm wrong.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When  you make *asynchronous* requests like your code does, the flow of execution does not wait for the response. It just continues along as though there was nothing there to prevent it (because there is nothing there). So your main function returns immediately.

The nested `return` statements you've provided are returning a value to the caller of those nested functions. So who is the caller? Well, you're passing those functions as an argument to some internal code, so the internal code is the caller, and that internal code probably doesn't care about the `return` value.

So what this means is that all those `return` statements are doing absolutely nothing useful because your main function already returned, and the code calling your functions is ignoring them.

So what do you do? Well, as you can see, you're receiving a `callback` function that gets passed to your `module.exports` function. So what you should do is pass the data that you would normally `return` as an argument to the `callback`. Then whatever function was passed as the `callback` will receive that data, and do whatever you want with it.

```
module.exports = function (req, res, callback) {
    if (req.session.authenticated) {
        // Accept user authentication.
        callback();
    } else {
        // Not authenticated. Try auto authentication.
        if(validator.check([validator.rulesHardwareId(req.param('hardwareId'))])){
            Device.findOne({hardwareId: req.param('hardwareId')}, function(err, device){
                if (err) {
                    callback(res.json({message: "You are not permitted to perform this action. You have to connect to the platform before. [Wrong hardwareId or DB error]", data: {err: err}, status: false}, 403));
                } else if (device) {
                    // Connect the device.
                    req.session.authenticated = true;
                    req.session.from = 'device';

                    // Search for the device's owner.
                    User.findOne({id: device.userId}, function(err, user){
                        if (err) {
                            callback(res.json({message: "DB error.", data: {err: err}, status: false}, 403));
                        } else if (user) {
                            // Add data about the user.
                            req.session.user = user;
                            callback();
                        } else {
                            callback(res.json({message: "Device found but device's owner doesn't found.", data: {err: err}, status: false}, 403));
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    callback(res.json({message: "You are not permitted to perform this action. You have to connect to the platform before. [Wrong hardwareId]", data: {err: err}, status: false}, 403));
                }
            });
        } else {
            callback(res.json({message: "You are not permitted to perform this action. You have to connect to the platform before. [Give hardwareId ?]", data: {}, status: false}, 403));
        }
    }
};
```

So your function would be invoked something like this:

```
 // This is the callback ------v
my_module(the_req, the_res, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        // do something with the error
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I won't do like this, I don't want to give to the callback method the object, but this answer was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a direct answer to your question. But I am sure that it will help others as its relevant.

---

## Consider the following cases:

#### Case 1: Where return is not used and the function is async.

```
(function caller(){
    var returnedValue;
    /* Following cannot be the case
    returnedValue = callee("TestParam");
    */
    calleeWithoutReturn("TestParam", function(returnFromCallback){
        console.log(returnFromCallback);
    });
})()//() is to init the function

function calleeWithoutReturn(params, callback){
    console.log("Received Param value", params); 
    callback("Return Value Here");
    /* Here the callback is actually the function which get passed over here. 
       You can actually call/execute it as many times as you want and it does that.
       Following is the sample code
    */
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
        callback("Return Value Here " + i);
    }
}
```

#### Case 2: Where return is used and the function is still async

```
(function caller(){
    var returnedValue;
    /* Following cannot be the case
    returnedValue = callee("TestParam");
    */
    calleeWithReturn("TestParam", function(returnFromCallback){
        console.log(returnFromCallback);
    });
})()//() is to init the function

function calleeWithReturn(params, callback){
    console.log("Received Param value", params); 

    //Try adding return here as well. It stops executing next statements and control exits.
    callback("Return Value Here"); 

    /* Here the callback is actually the function which get passed over here. 
       You can actually call/execute it as many times as you want and it does that.
       Following is the sample code
    */
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
        return callback("Return Value Here " + i); //When return executed it exits from the for loop & this functino function.
    }
}
```

#### Case 3: Where return is used and function is sync.

```
(function caller(){
    var returnedValue;
    returnedValue = calleeWithReturn("TestParam");
    console.log("caller received the return value:", returnedValue);

})()//() is to init the function

function calleeWithReturn(params){
    console.log("Received Param value", params);
    return "Params returned from callee function " + params 
}
```

#### Case 4: Where return is not used and function is sync.

```
(function caller(){
    var returnedValue;
    returnedValue = calleeWithReturn("TestParam");
    console.log("caller received the return value:", returnedValue); //Undefined if you dont return any value.

})()//() is to init the function

function calleeWithReturn(params){
    console.log("Received Param value", params);
    //If you dont return the function always returns 'Undefined'
    //return "Params returned from callee function " + params
}
```

Hope now you can make you the actual use case of return in different cases.